# Selenium Webdriver - how to close the first pop up window and go to the actual page

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to automate the webpage "http://www.quikr.com",when I open this you will get a pop up window first saying "Please Choose Your Location" then after closing it , I can see the main page of quikr.

I tried closing that Popup page by automation ,but not able to do

Tried using xpath

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='csclose']/strong")).click();
```

Tried using className

```
 driver.findElement(By.className("cs-close cs-close-v2")).click();
```

Tried using id

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("csclose")).click();
```

Please help me with this

Comment: What happens when you try them?

Answer (score 2):

to close multiple popups in webdriver and switch to parent window

```
String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();

        Set<String> pops=driver.getWindowHandles();
        {
        Iterator<String> it =pops.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            String popupHandle=it.next().toString();
            if(!popupHandle.contains(parent))
            {
            driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
            System.out.println("Popu Up Title: "+ driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle).getTitle());
            driver.close();
```

Comment: Why is "SET" used?

Comment: SET is class in selenium to store all windows as string

Answer (score 2):

The Following Code Works for Me to Handle Pop Up/ Alerts in Selenium Webdriver
Just Copy Paste this Code After the Event which is triggering the Pop up/Alert i.e after clicking on save.

```
if(driver.switchTo().alert() != null)
{
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText = alert.getText();
    alert.dismiss(); // alert.accept();

}
```

in your case you try to run this code at starting of the code bcz it will directly close the pop up

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a JavaScript modal, when the page finishes loading the JavaScript code could still be running. The solution is to wait until the button to close the modal be displayed, close it and then follow with your test. Like this:

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("csclose")));

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("csclose")).Click();
```

Tested myself and works fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks all for the response and Thanks to Code Enthusiastic ,your piece of code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried it in ruby and this one works
see if this can help you in any way :)

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rubygems'

class Tclogin < Test::Unit::TestCase                                                        #------------ define a class----------------

    def setup
    @@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox                                         
    @@driver.navigate.to "http://www.quikr.com"                 #---- call url----
    @@wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 60) # seconds                     #----define wait------
    end

    def test_login
     @@driver.find_element(:css, "strong").click
    end
end
```

you can also use follwing xpath

```
@@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[@id='csclose']/strong").click
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void closePopup() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.quikr.com/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("csclose"))).click();
        System.out.println("Successfully closed the start Popup");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.findElement(By.Id("csclose")).click();` I hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Simple pressing Alt + F4 buttons worked for me, e.g.:

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body div div img")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.F4));
```