# Mechanize check all radio buttons before form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, screen-scraping, mechanize

For a school project, I'm trying to scrape the content of multiple choices questions (to study for French SATs.
[screenshot of the webpage that I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qXTA.png)

My scraper works. However, the page uses javascript to get the first 5 questions then you need to answer each question and click on a next button then you have access to the 5-10 questions.

In the inspector, I compared the two html doc (before and after clicking on the radiobuttons + next button), I put both files at the end of the post (the first html doc has a form of type="get" while the second has a form of type "post")

Thus, I used the gem Mechanize and tried to click on all inputs and then the button.
Sadly, it doesn't work and I seem to have the same html file before and after running my code using Mechanize.

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'
require 'mechanize'

url = 'https://www.letudiant.fr/quiz/bac/histoire-geographie/quiz-bac-histoire-geographie-l-es-s-l-asie-du-sud-et-de-l-est-les-enjeux-de-la-croissance/question.html'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)
form = agent.page.form_with(:class => "c-form")
form.radiobuttons.each do |button|
  button.check
end

# check if button.checked?
puts "============"
form.radiobuttons.each do |button|
  puts button.checked?
end
puts "============"


puts "************"

page = agent.submit(form)
puts page.parser.text
puts "************"
```

This returns this in the console: meaning that Mechanize clicked on every radiobutton (each question has 3 radiobuttons, thus mechanize clicks on all of them but only the last one remained clicked (for each question), explaining the false - false - true repetition for each question)[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9OSE.png)

```
============
false
false
true
false
false
true
false
false
true
false
false
true
false
false
true
============
************
#<Mechanize::Page:0x00007fb942c50e38>

    
                                                                
        
        Test Quiz Bac L/ES/S - Histoire-Géographie  - L'Asie du Sud et de l'Est - L'Etudiant
        



                                                                       Quiz  Bac        Quiz Bac L/ES/S - Histoire-Géographie - L'Asie du Sud et de l'Est                Étape 1         Étape 2                 1) Mumbai est :              Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.                a) la capitale politique de l’Union indienne.               b) la capitale économique et culturelle de l’Union indienne.               c) la capitale culturelle de l’Union indienne.                 2) Que sont les slums ?              Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.                a) Le nom des bidonvilles en Inde.               b) Le nom des quartiers aisés en Inde.               c) Le nom des décharges en Inde.                 3) Comment évolue la population de l’agglomération de Mumbai ?              Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.                a) Une croissance lente.               b) Une stagnation.               c) Une croissance rapide.                 4) Quelle est la part de la population de l’Asie du Sud et de l’Est dans la population mondiale ?              Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.                a) 2/3.               b) 1/4.               c) 1/2.                 5) Que signifie « PMA » ?              Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.                a) Pays mal avancés.               b) Pays les moins avancés.               c) Pays mal adaptés.                            
 ##################
Attention ! Veuillez répondre à toutes les questions.
#######################
                          Étape suivante                                                                          Articles les plus lus              Bac S 2018 : tous les sujets et corrigés               Grand oral du nouveau bac : ce qui vous attend               On connaît la liste des œuvres au programme du bac de français 2020               Pourquoi prendre latin ou grec en option en terminale ?               Complémentaires ou expertes, à quoi ressembleront les options maths en terminale ?               Bac STMG 2018 : tous les sujets et corrigés               Nouveau bac : vous aurez les résultats des E3C le 15 mars               Que se passera-t-il si vous ratez votre bac en 2020 ?               Bac 2019 : les citations à (bien) utiliser à l’épreuve de philo               E3C : ce que vous risquez si vous les manquez           window._taboola = window._taboola || [];  _taboola.push({  mode: 'thumbnails-right-rail',  container: 'taboola-right-rail-thumbnails',  placement: 'Right Rail Thumbnails',  target_type: 'mix'  });                                 

                            Quiz Bac L/ES/S - Histoire-Géographie  - L'Asie du Sud et de l'Est                        

************
```

The sentence "Attention ! Veuillez répondre à toutes les questions." between ###### in the console, means that Mechanize tried to submit the form but had not clicked on every radiobutton [Like here when I try to click without having clicked on the radiobuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1kAq.png)

Here is the code (found in the inspector) before clicking on every radiobutton and clicking on the next button:

```html
<form class="c-form has-error" method="post" data-frm="quiz" data-frm-legacy-final-step-action="/test/quiz/validation.html?time=1583184886" data-frm-init="1">
   <div data-sln-scrollnav="" data-eng-scrollable="" class="c-scrollnav has-more-on-right">
      <nav class="c-simple-nav c-scrollnav__scroller" data-sln-scroller="">
         <ul class="  c-simple-nav__list  c-simple-nav__list--progress " data-sln-inner="">
            <li class="c-simple-nav__item">  <a class="  c-simple-nav__link  is-active is-clickable " href="#" data-frm-legacy-multi-step="Etape 1">  Étape 1 </a>  </li>
            <li class="c-simple-nav__item">  <a class="  c-simple-nav__link  " href="#" data-frm-legacy-multi-step="Etape 2">  Étape 2 </a>  </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <ol class="c-quiz__question-list">
      <li class="c-quiz-question has-error" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  1) Mumbai est : </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21887" value="66881">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) la capitale politique de l’Union indienne. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21887" value="66883">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) la capitale économique et culturelle de l’Union indienne. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21887" value="66885">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) la capitale culturelle de l’Union indienne. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question has-error" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  2) Que sont les slums ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21889" value="66887">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) Le nom des bidonvilles en Inde. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21889" value="66889">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) Le nom des quartiers aisés en Inde. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21889" value="66891">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) Le nom des décharges en Inde. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question has-error" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  3) Comment évolue la population de l’agglomération de Mumbai ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21891" value="66893">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) Une croissance lente. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21891" value="66895">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) Une stagnation. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21891" value="66897">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) Une croissance rapide. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question has-error" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  4) Quelle est la part de la population de l’Asie du Sud et de l’Est dans la population mondiale ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21893" value="66899">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) 2/3. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21893" value="66901">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) 1/4. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21893" value="66903">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) 1/2. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question has-error" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  5) Que signifie « PMA » ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21895" value="66905">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) Pays mal avancés. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21895" value="66907">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) Pays les moins avancés. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21895" value="66909">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) Pays mal adaptés. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <div class="c-form__errors">
      <div class="c-block-error">
         <div class="c-block-error__title">
            <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
               <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
               </svg>
            </div>
            Attention ! Veuillez répondre à toutes les questions.  
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" data-frm-legacy-multi-step-input="" name="step">  <input type="hidden" name="previousStep" value="">  <input type="hidden" name="nextStep" value="2">  <input type="hidden" name="idOrigine" value="1">  <input type="hidden" name="legacyFinalStepAction" value="/quiz/bac/histoire-geographie/quiz-bac-histoire-geographie-l-es-s-l-asie-du-sud-et-de-l-est-les-enjeux-de-la-croissance/conclusion.html?time=1583184886" ?="">   
   <div class="c-quiz__actions">
      <button class="c-button c-button--medium c-button--rounded c-button--light-border u-themed is-active u-typo--upper" type="button" data-frm-legacy-multi-step="next">
         <span>Étape suivante</span>  
         <svg class="c-icon-svg">
            <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-chevron-right"></use>
         </svg>
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is the html code that I want to get (found in the inspector after having clicked on every radiobutton and clicking on the next button:

```
<form class="c-form" method="post" data-frm="quiz" data-frm-legacy-final-step-action="/test/quiz/validation.html?time=1583187387" data-frm-init="1">
   <div data-sln-scrollnav="" data-eng-scrollable="" class="c-scrollnav has-more-on-right">
      <nav class="c-simple-nav c-scrollnav__scroller" data-sln-scroller="">
         <ul class="  c-simple-nav__list  c-simple-nav__list--progress " data-sln-inner="">
            <li class="c-simple-nav__item">  <a class="  c-simple-nav__link  is-clickable " href="#" data-frm-legacy-multi-step="Etape 1">  Étape 1 </a>  </li>
            <li class="c-simple-nav__item">  <a class="  c-simple-nav__link  is-active is-clickable " href="#" data-frm-legacy-multi-step="Etape 2">  Étape 2 </a>  </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <ol class="c-quiz__question-list">
      <li class="c-quiz-question" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  6) Parmi ces trois États, quel est celui dont la population croît la plus vite ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21897" value="66911">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) L’Inde. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21897" value="66913">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) Le Japon. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21897" value="66915">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) La Chine. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  7) Lequel de ces États est une démocratie ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21899" value="66917">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) La Chine. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21899" value="66919">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) L’Inde. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21899" value="66921">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) La Corée du Nord. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  8) Les relations économiques entre la Chine et le Japon se caractérisent par : </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21901" value="66923">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) des conflits. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21901" value="66925">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) de la concurrence. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21901" value="66927">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) de la complémentarité. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  9) À quelle instance la Chine refuse-t-elle la candidature du Japon ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21903" value="66929">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) L’ONU. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21903" value="66931">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) L’OMC. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21903" value="66933">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) Le Conseil de sécurité de l’ONU. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="c-quiz-question" data-frm-validate="[ 'required' ]">
         <h5 class="c-quiz-question__title">  10) Quel État est chargé d’assurer la protection militaire du Japon ? </h5>
         <div class="c-block-error">
            <div class="c-block-error__title">
               <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
                  <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                     <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
                  </svg>
               </div>
               Veuillez sélectionner une réponse.  
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="c-quiz-question__options">
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21905" value="66935">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  a) Le Royaume-Uni. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21905" value="66937">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  b) Les États-Unis. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">
               <input type="radio" name="question_21905" value="66939">   <span class="c-radio-label__label">  c) La Chine. </span>   
               <div class="c-radio__indicator"></div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <div class="c-form__errors">
      <div class="c-block-error">
         <div class="c-block-error__title">
            <div class="c-block-bubble c-block-bubble--error">
               <svg class="c-icon-svg" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlink:href="/svg/etu.sprite.svg#icon-exclamation"></use>
               </svg>
            </div>
            Attention ! Veuillez répondre à toutes les questions.  
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Edit: I added some code and details to be more precise, I hope my problem is easier to understand.

Comment: need some more info to help you solve this ... is the page processing the form submission using Javascript? In which case you'd probably have an easier time using an automated browser such as Selenium, as opposed to a HTML parser like mechanize.

Comment: Mechanize should be able to do it. It sounds that the "next step" button isn't a <input type="submit"> so mechanize won't submit the form. try using form.button_with(:class => "c-button").click to get the next step then submit using the actual submit button.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". When asking for help debugging we need the minimim input data (the HTML) that duplicates the problem in the question itself. Without that you're asking us to download the page, determine which part is causing problems, then write a harness to use your code. We also need to know exactly what you expect for results.

Comment: Some more reading: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".
"[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
"[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)"

Answer (score 0):

There are more checkboxes on page 2.

The resulting page source code shows 5 answers and 15 checkboxes, but I visited the page and saw 10 questions with 30 checkboxes in total. That's the reason for the French error message that not all checkboxes are ticked.

Check page 1 using the following code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('https://www.letudiant.fr/quiz/bac/histoire-geographie/quiz-bac-histoire-geographie-l-es-s-l-asie-du-sud-et-de-l-est-les-enjeux-de-la-croissance/question.html')
form = agent.page.form_with(:class => "c-form")

puts form.inspect
```

There are two different forms on the page as you can see if you loop over `page.forms` and `form.fields`:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('https://www.letudiant.fr/quiz/bac/histoire-geographie/quiz-bac-histoire-geographie-l-es-s-l-asie-du-sud-et-de-l-est-les-enjeux-de-la-croissance/question.html')
agent.page.forms.each do |form|
  pp form
  form.fields.each do |field|
  pp field
  end
end
```

"[Getting Started With Mechanize](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html)" will help.

You need to click the button on the bottom and then repeat the same action on page 2 before submitting the form.

There does not seem to be an option as the form changes using JavaScript.

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered and used Selenium to act as browser and thus perform the actions I asked it to do. It kind of work and I managed to have access to the rest of the page ```code ```

Comment: Good to know, I have read something about Selenium as well. The post below is basically a new question though.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags when you change your answer. SImply modify it to incorporate the new information as if it'd been there previously. We can see what changed and when if we need to.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered and used Selenium to act as browser and thus perform the actions I asked it to do. It kind of works, and I managed to have access to the rest of the page:

```rb
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
url = "https://www.letudiant.fr/quiz/bac/histoire-geographie/quiz-bac-histoire-geographie-l-es-s-l-asie-du-sud-et-de-l-est-les-enjeux-de-la-croissance/question.html"
driver.navigate.to url
driver.manage.window.maximize

sleep(3)
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)

name = wait.until {

  container = driver.find_elements(:class, "c-quiz-question")
  container.each do |element|
    puts element.text
  end

  puts "=========="

  radio_buttons = driver.find_elements(:class, "c-radio-label")
  radio_buttons.each do |button|
     button.click
  end

  puts "========="

  driver.find_element(:class, "c-button").click

}
```

These are the results in the console:

```rb
1) Mumbai est :
a) la capitale politique de l’Union indienne.
b) la capitale économique et culturelle de l’Union indienne.
c) la capitale culturelle de l’Union indienne.
2) Que sont les slums ?
a) Le nom des bidonvilles en Inde.
b) Le nom des quartiers aisés en Inde.
c) Le nom des décharges en Inde.
3) Comment évolue la population de l’agglomération de Mumbai ?
a) Une croissance lente.
b) Une stagnation.
c) Une croissance rapide.
4) Quelle est la part de la population de l’Asie du Sud et de l’Est dans la population mondiale ?
a) 2/3.
b) 1/4.
c) 1/2.
5) Que signifie « PMA » ?
a) Pays mal avancés.
b) Pays les moins avancés.
c) Pays mal adaptés.
==========
=========
6) Parmi ces trois États, quel est celui dont la population croît la plus vite ?
a) L’Inde.
b) Le Japon.
c) La Chine.
7) Lequel de ces États est une démocratie ?
a) La Chine.
b) L’Inde.
c) La Corée du Nord.
8) Les relations économiques entre la Chine et le Japon se caractérisent par :
a) des conflits.
b) de la concurrence.
c) de la complémentarité.
9) À quelle instance la Chine refuse-t-elle la candidature du Japon ?
a) L’ONU.
b) L’OMC.
c) Le Conseil de sécurité de l’ONU.
10) Quel État est chargé d’assurer la protection militaire du Japon ?
a) Le Royaume-Uni.
b) Les États-Unis.
c) La Chine.
==========
```

However, to do so I had to manually close a pop-up that appears in the Selenium browser and if I don't close it manually, I have a `ElementClickInterceptedError` that kills my program.

Is there any way to close this pop up with Ruby inside Selenium?

```
 element click intercepted: Element <label class="  c-radio-label u-themed  ">...</label> is not clickable at point (476, 499). Other element would receive the click: <div class="sd-cmp-39-hc" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">...</div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)
```

Comment: Not ruby but an option: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/how-to-close-pop-up-window-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Ruby example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738888/how-to-dismiss-popups-with-selenium-webdriver-in-ruby I hope this helps, I have no clue about Selenium.

Comment: Another post about Selenium and Pop Ups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465136/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-the-first-pop-up-window-and-go-to-the-actual-p/20260487

Comment: Please do NOT add answers unless you intend for it to be the selected solution to the problem. Answers are not for continuations of the question, nor are they for summarizations or to show how another answer helped solve the question. Stack Overflow is like an online reference book of programming questions and their solutions, not a message board or forum. Also, please don't use "edit" or "update" tags when you change your answer. SImply modify it to incorporate the new information as if it'd been there previously. We can see what changed and when if we need to.